# React adding class to element

Tags: reactjs, preact

I am trying add a class name to an element but its not working. Am I missing something with JSX components?

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import { Link } from 'preact-router/match';
import style from './style';

export default class Header extends Component {
        render() {
                return (
                        <header class={style.header}>
                                <h1>Lancaster County Apple Corps</h1>
                                <img class="site-icon" src="assets/icons/icon-128x128.png" alt="LCAC site icon" />
                                <nav>
                                        <Link activeClassName={style.active} href="/">Home</Link>
                                        <Link activeClassName={style.active} href="/benefits">Benefits</Link>
                                        <Link activeClassName={style.active} href="/cost">Cost</Link>
                                        <Link activeClassName={style.active} href="/memberForm">Member Form</Link>
                                        <Link activeClassName={style.active} href="/meetingNotes">Meeting Notes</Link>
                                        <Link activeClassName={style.active} href="/links">Links</Link>
                                </nav>
                        </header>
                );
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that you must use `className` to set HTML's `class` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be `className` not `class`.  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: I tried that and it still is not applying the styles

Comment: And in your style css do you have a class named `.header {}`?

Comment: .header .site-icon {
   width: 45px;
}

Comment: and you changed site-icon `class` to `className`? If so then I don't know. Try importing the full style url, e.g. `./style.css`

Comment: You're still using class instead of classname: `<header class={style.header}>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `.header .site-icon { width: 45px; }` in your styles as commented above,  can you try `<header className="site-icon">` ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `className` instead of `class`.

[Explanation in my article](https://blog.fromaline.com/why-you-have-to-use-classname-in-react-but-not-in-preact), if you want to take a deep dive.